# android keyboard shows for a split second after opening the camera

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm working on my first app in android studio, and I encountered something that I can't find an explanation or solution for. (Don't mind the silly layout and backgrounds, I had fun while creating it)

What happens is that I have two textfields. When you click on them, a keyboard will appear. You write what you need to write and press done, after which the keyboard will disappear. And that works fine.

However, when i press any one of my 3 buttons below, the keyboard appears for a splitsecond. For example, when you click the Take Picture button, it will open the camera. And it does, but for maybe half a second it displays the keyboard, before it disappears again and the camera opens.

Functionality-wise everything works as I want it to, but it really bothers me that the camera keeps showing for the splitsecond. I've tried google and my trusted book on android programming, I've looked over the code and tried to find something that indicated that a keyboard was in play upon button click. I've tried inserting :

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

And several variations thereof. I've tried over five different solutions that I found here on stackoverflow, but nothing worked. It really puzzles me how in the hell this keyboard shows for such a short time. Any suggestions? I think I could solve it if I just knew why this happened, but I really have no idea so I dont know what to look at for a solution.

[image]

Comment: on button click hide keyboard first, then perform action.

Comment: Please, edit your question, add relevant information, such as the `YouActivity_layout.xml`, the `YouActivityClass` and perhaps the Intent that launched your activity... If I had to guess, your button either sets focus on a `TextView` (or child of it), or you cycle in any View that asks for input. But there are way too many posibilities without any code...... finally, add the scenario where you are running this code... is it a device? a emulator? What is the API level, what is the OEM that created that image, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I justed wanted to update on the problem. I never found a solution, so I kept working on the app. I was using genymotion as an emulator, and when I started testing on my phone instead, I never experienced the keyboard showing up. So I guess it was some sort of genymotion problem. I never found out what it was exactly that caused the problem to happen, but I wanted to update my question in case someone runs into the same problem.